# rails 5 - show route not working or generating

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am digging into rails 5.2.0. I am working on a dead simple app to get my feet wet on anything new (mainly work in production w/ rails 3 & 4 apps).

I am on my index path, rendering something like

```
<ul>
    <% @questions.each do |question| %>
        <li><%= link_to question.title, questions_path(question.id) %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

My controller looks like

```
def index
    @questions = Question.all
end

def new
    @question = Question.new
end

def create
    @question = Question.new(title: params['question']['title'], body: params['question']['body'])

    if @question.save 
        redirect_to '/'
    else
        redirect_to '/questions/new'
    end
end

def show
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
end
```

and my routes look like

```
get '/' => 'questions#index'

get '/questions/new' => 'questions#new'

post '/questions' => 'questions#create'

get '/questions/:id' => 'questions#show'
```

This is all fine, but when i go to click on the links in my index, i get a path that's `http://localhost:3000/questions.8`, and when i run `rails routes`, I get

```
Prefix Verb URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
                          GET  /                                                                                        questions#index
                          GET  /questions/:id(.:format)                                                                 questions#show
            questions_new GET  /questions/new(.:format)                                                                 questions#new
                questions POST /questions(.:format)                                                                     questions#create
```

and if you notice it did not generate a path for the show route. The only thing that works is doing something like this in the index

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <li><%= link_to question.title, "/questions/#{question.id}" %></li>
<% end %>
```

which is fine but defeats the whole purpose of these routes.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong or forgetting? Is this a rails 5 thing, or just something dumb in my code?

Comment: the second path in your routes output is your show route

Comment: @sa77 doing `<%= link_to question.title, questions_path(question) %>` returns a route that looks like `http://localhost:3000/questions.1`

Comment: try defining as `get '/questions/:id' => 'questions#show', :as => :question` then use it as `question_path(question)` (notice no plural) .. but you're better off using `resources`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `questions_path` routes to `/questions`, so when you do,

```
link_to question.title, questions_path(question.id)
```

You're getting `/questions` with the `question.id` appended as `.8` (because `questions_path` doesn't expect an argument).

Instead, shouldn't you just do:

```
root 'questions#index'
resources :questions
```

Which would give you:

```
          root GET    /                                 questions#index
     questions GET    /questions(.:format)              questions#index
               POST   /questions(.:format)              questions#create
  new_question GET    /questions/new(.:format)          questions#new
 edit_question GET    /questions/:id/edit(.:format)     questions#edit
      question GET    /questions/:id(.:format)          questions#show
               PATCH  /questions/:id(.:format)          questions#update
               PUT    /questions/:id(.:format)          questions#update
               DELETE /questions/:id(.:format)          questions#destroy
```

(You can prune the routes using `:only` or `:except`, if you like.)

And then you can do:

```
<ul>
  <% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <li><%= link_to question.title, question %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Rails should infer the correct route from the `question` variable and create a link to `/questions/8` as described in the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to).

Answer (score 0):

You should define your show route as

```
get '/questions/:id' => 'questions#show', :as => :question
```

then use it as `question_path(question)` (notice no plural) because `questions_path` is already taken by the route to `questions#index`.

But you're better off using rails' routes helper method `resources` if you want cleaner solution.

```
resources :questions, :only => [:index, :new, :create, :show]
```